# Transaction escalates when using TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption

Tags: c#, async-await, distributed-transactions

I have a small web api server written in C# using async/await. The Net version is 4.5.2

Everything is working fine except that I use TransactionScope for some calls and the underlying transaction is escalated to a distributed one. Since I use async/await for my db calls I use TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption. The SQL server is running version 2008 r2 so it should be able to handle multiple calls without escelating the transaction. All calls are made to the same database with the same connection string.

All SQL connections are done in using statements and I'm not nesting any of them. Each call to the database is awaited before another is done so there should never be two connections active a the same time in one transaction, unless I have misunderstood how async/await works. I'm using Dapper if that might impact things.

Am I missing something obvious or do I need to rewrite my code to use the same connection for all operation in the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel really stupid, missed that Pooling was disabled in the connection string. Removed `Pooling=false` and the transaction does not escalate to a distributed state.